# Print the pushd command on the cmd using c#

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to write a command like pushd \172.x.x.x\something\something using c#. I just want to map the network path on the local machine using pushd. If I am doing the same by explicitly open the cmd n typing the pushd command , it is connecting the network path on the local machine. I want to do it by using c#.Any help would be appreciated. Below is my code :

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string strCmdText;
        strCmdText = "pushd" + @"\172.x.x.x\something\something";
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("CMD.exe", strCmdText);
    }
```

Comment: ok, so whats the problem? an error? unexpected results?

Comment: it is not showing any error but also not sending that command to cmd promt.

Comment: What use is a single `pushd` command to a console? Without follow-up commands, it seems kind of useless.

Comment: Try this `strCmdText = "/K pushd " + @"\172.x.x.x\something\something";`

Comment: You do know you dont have a space between pushd and the \ ?

Comment: I tried this but nothing happened

Answer (score 1):

There's a space missing between 'pushd' and the second argument.
Change it to something like this:

```
strCmdText = "pushd" + " " + @"\172.x.x.x\something\something";
```

Answer (score 0):

Does it help specifying /C or /K first in strCmdText?
Does it help using double backslash: `\\172.x.x.x`

Comment: when I am doing so , I am getting a line on top of the cmd that "The system cannot find the path specified". Can anyone please help. I am stuck here.